# Facebook in-app browser deep links problems for Android and iOs

Tags: android, ios, facebook, redirect, deep-linking

I am building the redirect service for facebook in-app browser, with the main objective:

A: When user clicks the link and has the app installed (3rd party) it should open the deep link in the app right away.
B: When user clicks the link and the app is not installed - it should just load the web page inside the facebook in-app browser.

For now I am having these problems:

1) On Android devices if I immediately redirect the user to the link: "intent://#Intent;package=com.app;scheme=com.app.web://deeplink_content;S.browser_fallback_url=https://google.com;end;" the play store appears right after the click, which is not correct behavior. More than that - when I hit "back" on Android control buttons - it redirects me back to facebook with the in-app browser already closed! So there is literally no way to open the link without having the app installed.

In chrome browser on mobile - this link redirects to fallback_url right away - which is what I need, actually.

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

2) On iOs devices this is the only way how it works:

```html
<body>
<script>
    window.location = "com.app.web://deep_link";

    setTimeout(
        function () {
            if (document.hasFocus() === true) {
                // fallback url 
                window.location = "https://google.com";
            }
        },
        100
    );
</script>
</body>
```

But it always prompts two questions one by one: "Do I want to leave facebook app" and then "Do I want to open this link in my app". And in case if the app is not installed - it's still asking if I want to leave facebook app first and then nothing happens.
But at least it works somehow, so I can live with it in comparison to Android...

I was looking for solution with Facebook App Links, tried to add metatags, but probably it's mostly for app developers, because it didn't help at all.

Please, help, I am desperate searching for solution :(

Comment: have you found a working solution. i had one with iframe. but actually it is not working.

Comment: nope. Gave up currently... Facebook looks to be very serious and doesn't allow people to leave their in-app browser in any way...